# Como Adicionar SSL Free no Azure? É Possível?

Tags: email, certificado-digital, ssl, microsoft-azure, domínio

**No Azure:**

Tenho uma conta no Azure onde criei um novo Site.
Para adicionar um Certificado SSL (Https) tive que alterar o plano de hospedagem de "Grátis" para "Básico" (no menu Escala).
Então me abriu a opção de subir um certificado (no menu Configurar).

**No GeoTrust:** (https://www.geotrust.com/)

Criei um certificado SSL Free. Contudo para aprovar o certificado eu teria de receber uma autorização em um e-mail para o mesmo domínio do certificado criado. O problema é que o meu site não tem domínio próprio e sim o domínio do azure: http://exemplo.azurewebsites.net.

**Como resolver isso? Como crio um certificado SSL Free para um domínio do azure?**

Comment: Achei um Site que gera Certificado SSL onde o e-mail de confirmação pode ser do Gmail: https://www.startssl.com/ contudo no momento está dando a seguinte mensagem: Over Capacity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa, fiz um post exatamente sober isso há um tempo atrás!

http://luisrudge.net/configurando-ssl-com-seu-dominio-no-azure-websites/

Abaixo, está a transcrição do post.

---

Nesse exemplo, vou utilizar um SSL grátis do Start SSL.

Registro no "StartSSL"

Para iniciar, vamos nos cadastrar no "StartSSL".

[Form de registro http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/1_1.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/1_1.png)
**Cadastre-se no site**

[Confirmação de código http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/2-1.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/2-1.png)
**Confirme o código recebido por e-mail**

[Continuar http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/3-1.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/3-1.png)
**Continue**

[Instalar certificado na máquina http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/4-1.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/4-1.png)
**Instalar o certificado na sua máquina**

[Certificado instalado http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/5-1.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/5-1.png)
**Certificado instalado**

Escolher domínio do SSL

Agora que já temos o certificado na nossa máquina, podemos adicionar domínios à nossa conta. É aqui que o dinheiro faz a diferença. O StartSSL grátis, faz uma verificação **muito** básica e, por isso, não é o SSL mais confiável do mundo.

O valor que você paga para cadastrar um SSL é, principalmente, proporcional à dois fatores:

- Rigidez na confirmação dos seus dados como dono do domínio
- Garantia financeira que o fornecedor te dá caso você tenha prejuízo financeiro com alguma falha de segurança com o SSL fornecido

Vamos lá!

[Digitar domínio http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/6-1.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/6-1.png)
**Digite o domínio**

[Confirmação por e-mail http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/7.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/7.png)
**Escolha o seu e-mail de cadastro**

[Confirmação de código http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/8.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/8.png)
**Novamente, confirme o código recebido por e-mail**

[Confirmação de autenticação http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/9.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/9.png)
**Continue**

Criando a chave privada

Depois de "confirmar" que você é o dono do domínio, crie a sua chave privada.

[Criar chave privada http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/10.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/10.png)
**Digite uma senha para que seja criada uma chave privada**

[Salvar chave privada http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/11.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/11.png)
**Salve a chave privada**

Criando o certificado

Depois de criar a chave privada, é necessário criar o certificado em si.

[Escolher o domínio http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/12.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/12.png)
**Escolha o domínio**

[Escolher o subdomínio http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/13.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/13.png)
**Escolha o subdomínio**

[Confirmação dos dados http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/14.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/14.png)
**Confirme os dados e continue**

[Copiar ou salvar certificado http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/15.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/15.png)
**Salve o certificado**

Gerando o .pfx para o Azure

Com o certificado em mãos, agora precisamos de um arquivo para importar no IIS (no Azure ou não).

[Descriptografar a chave privada http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/16.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/16.png)
**Descriptografe a chave privada com sua senha**

[Copiar a chave http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/17.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/17.png)
**Copie a chave descriptografada**

[Gerar PFX http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/18.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/18.png)
**Insira a chave descriptografada, o certificado e sua senha**

[PFX gerado http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/19.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/19.png)
**Salve e renomeie o arquivo de .p12 para .pfx**

Configurando o Azure Website

Pronto! Agora vamos no Azure configurar o que é necessário.

Para poder usar SSL, é necessário fazer o upgrade para o modo Padrão. Só isso já aumentaria o valor para manter o site, mas ainda tem mais. Para utilizar o SSL no Azure Websites, [o custo é de $9/mês](http://www.windowsazure.com/pt-br/pricing/details/web-sites/#service-ssl).

Mas é isso aí, se queremos oferecer segurança aos usuários, temos que implementar o SSL. Bora!

[Upgrade para Padrão http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/1.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/1.png)
**Faça upgrade para o modo Padrão**

[Carregar um certificado http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/2.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/2.png)
**Clique em 'carregar um certificado'**

[Carregar um certificado http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/3.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/3.png)
**Faça o upload do arquivo .pfx**

[Não esqueça da data de expiração http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/4.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/4.png)
**Não se esqueça da data de expiração!**

[Associe os endpoints SSL http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/5.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/5.png)
**Associe os endpoints SSL do certificado**

[Pronto :) http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/6.png](http://luisrudge.net/content/images/2013/Nov/6.png)
**Pronto :)**

Comment: desenvolve a tua resposta. Esse link por algum motivo pode ficar desactivo, e a resposta fica inválida.

Comment: não concordo muito com isso, já que a resposta fica excessivamente grande e o blog é meu, mas tá aí. Valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Usando Let's Encrypt *(fiz o passo a passo hoje - 25/06/2018 - e funciona!)*

**O passo a passo abaixo funciona quando você cria um WebApp Linux no azure.**

*Se seu WebApp é Windows você pode criar um temporário Linux, configurar os domínios que irão receber os certificados e depois apagar esse WebApp temporário e configurar os domínios no WebApp oficial e adicionar os certificados nele.*

1. Adicionar Domínios Personalizados no portal Azure.
2. Abrir interface SSH no Azure
3. Executar comandos abaixo:

   su root

   cd /home

   apt-get update

   apt-get install git

   git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt

   cd /home/letsencrypt

   ./letsencrypt-auto certonly
4. Informar esses parâmetros no Let's Encrypt que terá sido aberto

   Authenticate: 3 Place files in webroot directory (webroot)

   Enter email address: seu e-mail

   Terms of Service: A

   Share your email: N

   Your domain name: dominio.com.br www.dominio.com.br

   Input the webroot: /home/site/wwwroot

   Select the webroot: 2
5. Executar comandos abaixo:

   apt-get install p7zip-full

   cd /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominio.com.br

   mkdir /home/site/wwwroot/cert

   cp * /home/site/wwwroot/cert

   cd /home/site/wwwroot/cert

   7z a cert.zip *
6. Faça download dos arquivos do certificado gerados em http://dominio.com/cert/cert.zip
7. Executar comandos abaixo:

   rm -rf /home/site/wwwroot/cert/
8. Descompacte os arquivos.
9. Acesse: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html e informe:

   Certificate File to Convert: cert.pem

   Type of Current Certificate: Standard PEM

   Type To Convert To: PFX/PKCS#12

   Private Key File: privkey.pem

   Chain Certificate File (optional): chain.pem

   Chain Certificate File 2 (optional): fullchain.pem

   PFX Password: uma-senha
10. Clique "Convert Certificate" e salve o arquivo
11. No porta Azure, acesse Configurações de SSL. Configure conforme abaixo:

    Carregar Certificado: cert.pfx

    Adicionar associação: para cada domínio, escolher o certificado e tipo SSL SNI